# Bubbling Event Design

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of `<td>`'s in a table that have onmouseover and onmouseout events. I would like for there to only be one event handler, say on the `<table>` itself that knows how to handle all the events to prevent so many event handlers on the page. Using native javascript, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events should bubble up to the table unless they are cancelled in the process from an element lower down in the hierarchy. You can setup event listeners for `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on the table and check if the target is a `<td>` cell. If so, then process those events. Here's a quick example.

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

table.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    if (target.nodeName == 'TD') {
        target.style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
    }
});
```

See the [compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) for mouse events. Since older versions of IE do not follow the DOM event registration model as per the w3c spec, you would have to use `attachEvent` to attach events for IE only.

Read up this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) to get a better understanding of the differences in IE and other browsers.

Checkout a non cross-browser [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/fNsUM/) here.

Comment: But will the events keep getting fired as I mouseover/out of the td's without ever leaving the table itself?

Comment: Yes, the event will fire for each child element contained in the table. Browsers may optimize this behavior to not fire the event at all if there are no listeners attached in the entire tree for that even type, but it's usually not a performance bottleneck, but in-fact a performance booster unless you have a huge number of cells of descendant elements, in which case it will fire whenever the mouse hovers in and out of any contained element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use unobtrusive javascript so that you have the two handlers set up for each  but it doesn't clutter up the page.  Use getElementsByTagName("td") to get the  - modify that as appropriate.  Then loop through and for each element, tableElem, tableElem.onMouseOver = function(){whatever... } and tableElem.onMouseOut = function(){whatever ... }.

You can make it terser if you want to use jQuery, e.g. $("td").mouseOver(function(){whatever;});

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
table.onmouseover = function(event) {
    var target = (event && event.target) || window.event.srcElement;
    if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'td') return;

    // do stuff
};
```